# angular ui-bootstrap on the tabs how to add href

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-route-segment

```
<tabset>
  <tab heading="{{nav.label}}"  ng-repeat="nav in vm.data" href="{{nav.url}}">
   <tabset class="subnav">
     <tab ui-href="{{item.state}}" href="{{item.state}}" heading="{{item.label}}" ng-repeat="item in nav.items">
     </tab>
   </tabset>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

I want to add href, but you can not click!
I used angular-ui-bootstrap and angular-route!
What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a mistake it isn't 'ui-href' but "ui-sref" and give a state name to it.
sref is for "state reference".

Comment: In addition, I do not use ui-router. Just use the official route

Comment: sorry i didn't understand when i saw angular-ui-bootstrap.

Comment: You just have to use 'href' and give a link to it, as usual. Can you show your route config ?

Comment: Have you ever used jhipster yet?
I am using their route

Comment: no sorry but i look at https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/ and it's a nice sample that you could use for routing

Comment: Yes! I would like to bind to the tabs!but does not work!

Comment: you add ng-click and the function get url in params and your function do window.location = myUrl

Comment: or you can add a <a> inside your tab and put the href on it